# python, find a range where a number belongs to, ranges were formed up from list of integers

Tags: python, range

In python,

There is a list of integers, every continuous integers in the list form up a range. For a given number, I want to find the range where the number belongs to, and return the range (or the start of the range). E.g.

The list:

```
[1, 8,   11, 20,   37, 66,   99, 120, ...... ,56000,59001, .....]
```

The number:

```
100
```

Result:

```
(99,12) OR 99
```

The numbers are in increasing order, and the formed regions do not overlap, the size of list is always the multiple of 2.

The list can be long, and there are lots of numbers need to be checked.

I tried to pack the integers into a intervalTree, and use the search() function for checking, but it seemed slow:

```
for i in integerList:
    t = IntervalTree(Interval(*iv) for iv in zip(*[iter(annotation_dict.get(i))] * 2))

t.search(theNumber)
```

Is it possible to do it faster or better? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your list is already sorted, the [bisect module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) is your friend. It will do the O(log(n)) search for you.
For instance the functions `bisect_right` and `bisect_left` are handy. If `bisect_right` returns an odd number, then you number is in a range and the beginning of that range is the returned value minus `1`. If it is even, then you number is between two different ranges of your list.
See the example code below, I subtract one from the result directly, so that what I test is a reverse compared to the explanation.

```
import bisect
loi = [1, 8, 11, 20, 37, 66, 99, 120, 56000, 59001]
idx = bisect.bisect_right(loi,100)-1

if idx%2 == 0:
    print loi[idx]
else:
    print "not in a range"
```

Comment: You are welcome @Xiangwu. I am glad this was helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can use a modification of binary search to improve the average time complexity.
1) start by comparing the given number to the middle element of the list. If it is bigger compare with middle of right half else compare it with middle of left half.
2)Continue the first step till you get the interval in which the number lies.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be faster, but here is a possible solution (especially if you need to avoid the overhead of creating the IntervalTree each time).

```
def find_range(num, the_list):
    midpt = len(the_list) / 2
    left_list = the_list[0:midpt]
    right_list = the_list[midpt:]
    if num >= left_list[midpt - 1] and num <= right_list[0]:
        rv = (left_list[midpt - 1], right_list[0])
    elif num < left_list[midpt - 1]:
        rv = find_range(num, left_list)
    else:
        rv = find_range(num, right_list)
    return rv
```

I tested it with a small sample, and it works as expected, but I would benchmark this solution against the IntervalTree solution to see if you gain/lose anything.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You could use Python's [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html?highlight=bisect#bisect.bisect_left) library as follows:

```
import bisect

loi = [1, 8, 11, 20, 37, 66, 99, 120, 56000, 59001]
index = bisect.bisect_left(loi, 100)

print "({},{})".format(loi[index-1], loi[index])
```

This would display the following output:

```
(99,120)
```

It assumes the value is within the first and last elements.